Unable to view tables in SSMS in Azure but can execute select
I am trying to grant a user sql server access in Azure but seems to having issues.
User should have read only access.
Must be able to view the tables /view/Programmability in SSMS
Able to click on view the underlying script definition.
Should NOT be able to create, Insert, delete, alter, modify.
This is what I did in Master DB
CREATE LOGIN test1 WITH PASSWORD = 'Test123%57';

CREATE USER test1 FROM LOGIN test1

In the actual DB
CREATE USER test1 FROM LOGIN test1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER test1 ;

Alter Role db_denydatawriter ADD Member test1 ;

GRANT SELECT TO test1

Grant VIEW DEFINITION To test1

After the above, the user can run any select query and get the results from any table (ex: select * from [PeopleTable])
But when trying to expand the Tables/Views/Programmability
enter image description here

Considering it's an Azure SQL Database, why not make a LOGINless USER, as the databases are contained. So CREATE the USER with the password; there's no need to the LOGIN.


Unable to view tables in SSMS in Azure but can execute select

Follow the below approach to view tables in SSMS.

Create a sample database and store some data into the sample tables.


Create login  with password by using below command in SSMS master db:
CREATE LOGIN firstUser WITH PASSWORD = '*****';


Create a user in master db by using the below command:
CREATE USER firstUser FROM LOGIN firstUser;


Create the same user in the db which you have created in the server. Make sure that user is present in the master db.
CREATE USER firstUser FROM LOGIN firstUser;


Grant permission to the user to select the data from the particular db by using the below command.
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::firstDb TO firstUser;


Grant permission to the user to view only the data but not to modify the data.
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::firstDB TO firstUser;



Below is the output where the user can view the data but cannot modify the data.

When the user tries to modifies the data then it throws the error as shown below:

As Thom suggests, data can be viewed by creating user with password instead of creating a login. To create user with password, follow the below approach:

Create a user with password both in master db and sample db created in the server as shown below.
CREATE USER secondUser WITH PASSWORD = '****';


Grant permission to the user to select the table from the db.
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::firstDb TO secondUser;


Grant permission to the user to view the data but not to modify the data.
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::firstDB TO secondUser;



Output:

When the user tries to modify the data then it throws the error as shown below:

